# Change color of statusBar using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I have an file marked navigationManager that handles the statusBar and navigationBar for each of my views.  The actual navigationBar is working properly but the statusBar is simply all white for some reason.  here is the code in the navigationManager for the statusBar...

```
-(UINavigationBar *)getStatusBarWithX:(float)fX
                                Y:(float)fY
                            width:(float)fW
                           height:(float)fH {

UINavigationBar *barReturn = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(fX, fY, fW, fH)];
barReturn.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
[barReturn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deepBlue.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

return barReturn;
```

}

Then on the main view controller I pull the code from the navigationManager like so...

```
float statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
UINavigationBar *statusBar = [self.navigationManager getStatusBarWithX:0
                                                                     Y:0
                                                                 width:self.view.frame.size.width
                                                                height:statusBarHeight];
```

Then I simply add this to the view

```
[self.view addSubview:statusBar];
```

The statusBar, however is displaying nothing but white above the navigationBar.   I am using objective c and am not sure why this is doing this now.  It just started happening recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.  I had to change the color itself instead of setting a background image

instead of...

```
[barReturn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deepBlue.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I did the following...

```
barReturn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:48.0/255.0 green:65.0/255.0 blue:151.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```